# Binding Errors with Lazy Loading and Angular Material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, lazy-loading

I'm currently trying to implement lazy loading into my Angular 15 app to reduce the bundle size when I build, but I'm running into issues with bindings and Angular Material.  When I compile my app I get a bunch of binding and Angular Material errors in all of my components.

For example: "Can't bind to ngClass since it isn't a known property of button" or "mat-divider is not a known element".  How do I go about fixing this?

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadComponent: () => import('./home-page/home-page.component').then(m => m.HomePageComponent)
  },
  {
    path: 'cardpool',
    loadComponent: () => import('./cardpool/cardpool.component').then(m => m.CardpoolComponent)
  },
  {
    path: 'decks',
    loadComponent: () => import('./decks/decks.component').then(m => m.DecksComponent)
  },
  {
    path: 'banlist',
    loadComponent: () => import('./banlist/banlist.component').then(m => m.BanlistComponent)
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    loadComponent: () => import('./about/about.component').then(m => m.AboutComponent)
  }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularMaterialModule } from './angular-material.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AngularMaterialModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

angular-material.module.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';


const materialModules = [
  MatButtonModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatDividerModule,
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatDialogModule
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ...materialModules
  ],
  exports: [
    ...materialModules
  ],
})

export class AngularMaterialModule { }
```

Snippet from one of the components

decks.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-decks',
  templateUrl: './decks.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./decks.component.scss']
})
export class DecksComponent {

  constructor() {
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

decks.component.html

```
<mat-divider class="divider"></mat-divider>
<div style="padding-bottom: 40px; margin-left: 20px;">
    <div style="width: 75%;">
        <span>Span 1</span>
        <span>Span 2</span>
        <span>Span 3<</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

decks.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { DecksComponent } from "./decks.component";
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [DecksComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MatDividerModule
    ],
    exports: [DecksComponent]
})

export class DecksModule {
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the `decks.component` module as well as the code where you're using `ngClass`?  I don't readily see from the code presented where the problem could be coming from so I'm guessing maybe you're not importing you material module into the module of your `decks.component`.  As far as the `ngClass`  it could be a syntax error with how you're using it.  Are you using square brackets with it like `[ngClass]=""`?

Comment: Updated my question to include the module.  For ngClass I'm using [ngClass]=""

Comment: ok it sounds like you're using the proper syntax for ngClass however I don't see in your code where you're using it to see what your condition is.  Now that I think about it I'm also a little lost on why you're importing all those material elements into your `AppModule` as well as importing the divider into your `DecksModule` because I'm guessing they should be exposed to the entire app by being imported into your `AppModule`.  Try commenting it out of your `AngularMaterialModule` to see if it will be recognized in your `DecksModule` and vica versa.

Comment: If you make a stackblitz demo I'll poke around at it to see if I can find the problem because looking at the code you're presenting I don't see what the problem is.  It could be as simple as a typo you're not catching.

Comment: I've since run into a different issue with lazy loading, but I have the stackblitz made in case you want to take a look at that anyway.  I just wasn't importing some of the angular material stuff correctly.  Here's the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xmhypt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html